# Fingerprint sensor not working on Ideapad Slim 5 although support is mentioned on fprint's website

Tags: ubuntu, kde, pam, kde-neon, fingerprint

The support for the fingerprint reader device I use (04f3:0c58 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint) is available according to [this](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) page but when I try to run `fprintd-enroll` I always get either of the following results:

1.

```
$ sudo fprintd-enroll
[sudo] password for sbeve72: 
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-disconnected
```

2. 

```
$ sudo fprintd-enroll -f left-index-finger
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling left-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-unknown-error
```

or it just gets stuck at

```
$ sudo fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
```

and nothing follows until I press Ctrl + C.

In the best case scenario, sometimes I get

```
$ sudo fprintd-enroll -f left-index-finger
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling left-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-completed
```

but then `enroll-verify` either gives this:

```
$ sudo fprintd-verify
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Listing enrolled fingers:
 - #0: right-index-finger
Verify started!
Verifying: right-index-finger
Verify result: verify-no-match (done)
```

or gets stuck at

```
$ sudo fprintd-verify
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Listing enrolled fingers:
 - #0: right-index-finger
 - #1: left-index-finger
Verify started!
Verifying: right-index-finger
```

System Info:

Model: Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5 15ITL05
OS: KDE Neon 5.23 (with KDE Plasma 5.23.4)

`lsusb` output:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c58 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b725 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Check that you have the latest firmware for the device with `fwupdmgr`.

Comment: I did, it says I have no updates available @jsbillings